# Card styling in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on a hiring page project to practice React and I can't figure out a way to style these cards properly

I want to style these cards in a way (sorry, I can't post images yet) that when I resize the page, inspect element, open in mobile view etc, it resizes on its own and not go outside the dimensions of the main page.

Code for Card component

```
const Card = () => {
    return openingData.map((el) => {
        return (
            <div className="card-container card">
                <div className="positions-container">{el.positions}</div>
                <div className="image-container">
                    <img src={el.logo} alt="" height="375" width="475" />
                </div>
                <div className="card-content">
                    <div clasName="title-container">
                        <b>
                            <h3>{el.title}</h3>
                        </b>
                    </div>
                    <div className="message-container">
                        <h5>{el.message}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="button-container">
                    <button className="buttons btn">Join Now!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
};
```

Code for Card-list component

```
const CardList = () => {
    return (
        <div className="card-list">
            <Card />
        </div>
    );
};
```

CSS

```
.card-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.922);
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.card-container:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card-list {
    width: 85vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add globally

```
   img {
     max-width: 100%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

give appropriate dimensions to your `card.container` so that all the content can have their boundary by specifying `max-width`